# How to fix AZ CLI error "The Resource '..' under resource group '..' was not found"?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am struggling to execute az cli commands related to resource groups.
I have set the correct subscription.
I can list the resource group with the command 'az group list'.
But I get errors when referring to the resource group in a command where mysql is involved, for example:

```
C:>az mysql server show --resource-group HHDevelopment --name hh-dev-test
The Resource 'Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers/hh-dev-test' under resource group 'HHDevelopment' was not found.
```

When I login to Azure portal, I can access the mysql server and the databases without any problem.
What should I do to get it working on the Azure Command Line Interface?

When I ask for a list databases in the resource group, I get a json formatted list of alert rules, components and databases.
So, the group and the database exists.
An example from the list is the following:

```
C:> az resource list --resource-group HHDevelopment`

`[...]
  {
    "id": "/subscriptions/0c839bc3-c0c3-470b-a62f-c4998fe000c0/resourceGroups/HHDevelopment/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/hh-dev-test/databases/Elp.Arrangement.10",
    "identity": null,
    "kind": "v12.0,user",
    "location": "westeurope",
    "managedBy": null,
    "name": "hh-dev-test/Elp.Arrangement.10",
    "plan": null,
    "properties": null,
    "resourceGroup": "HHDevelopment",
    "sku": {
      "capacity": 5,
      "family": null,
      "model": null,
      "name": "Basic",
      "size": null,
      "tier": "Basic"
    },
    "tags": null,
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
  },
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you think it exists? you show that it finds some sql server in that resource group, whilst your command is looking for mysql server, i just you just mistakenly try to get sql server resource using command for mysql server

I suppose you are looking for these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest